# c# - Advancing datetime (duration) from current date

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to display date advancing the current date (like validity date) on a button click. My code are as follows:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDateToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
        lblValiDate = <output date: 5 days from the current>
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I just added ToString("MMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm") to display it! Sorry for not noticing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current DateTime as a DateTime type, then you can use the AddDays extension method to increment the Date.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dateInFiveDays = dateToday.AddDays(5);

    lblDateToday = dateToday.ToString("MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
    lblValiDate = dateInFiveDays.ToString("MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString(@"MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) to add days to your current date.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

lblDateToday = dt.ToString("MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
lblValiDate = dt.AddDays(5).ToString("MMMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
```

Fiddler [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QWwM50)

Comment: That demo seems so helpful. Thank you for the link!

Comment: @PaulEmmanuelAustria can you close the question if it helped and answered your question?